# Knowing the original class if casted to an object class

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, casting

If I have two classes like these:

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual void speak()
    {
        //TOSPEAK
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void speak()
    {
        //TODOGSPEAK
    }
}
```

If I'm passing an object of any of those two classes to a method which has a similar form to that

```
void method (Animal ob1);
```

If I called the speak method which one would be called if I passed each object? And is there a way to know which object type has been passed to the method?

Comment: @downvoter: While downvoting is anonymous, an explanation would certainly go a long way here.  Your reasoning doesn't seem at all obvious to me.  If it's a duplicate, vote to close or flag as such.

Comment: It's worth noting that testing the type of object generally indicates a design flaw somewhere; the whole point of virtual methods and polymorphism is that you *don't* have to know exactly the type of object you are dealing with, just that it implements some particular interface (I'm using "interface" in the general sense, not the C# feature -- a base class with virtual methods defines an interface).

Comment: not the downvoter, however: As a matter of maintainability: you should avoid wanting to know the answer to this question :-).  If you need to the type of the object, you abstraction (the API here) is leaky.  After all, apparently being able to "speak" isn't enough to work with that animal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if I called the speak method which one would be called if I passed each object a

If the object you're passing into `method` is just an `Animal`, `Animal.speak()` will be called.  If it is a dog, `Dog.speak()`  will be called.  That's the whole point of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

> Is there's a way to know which object type has been passed to the method

You can use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) or [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operators:

```
if(ob1 is Dog)
{

}
```

Note: As everyone have already mentioned, if you need to check the type of your object,that's not a good idea and you should probably reconsider your design. If you want to perform different actions for different types that's the point of overriding methods. If that's not the problem you can create overloaded methods for each type instead of checking the type in one method and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Given the apparent scope of this question - basic, beginners OO design - I really want to emphasize that this is a **bad idea**.  Don't get in the habit of using the `is` and `as` operators - you're missing the point of polymorphism.

Comment: Given that "bad idea" has been stated *three times* in this post already, I think everyone gets it now.  Not for nothing, but they *did* put the operators in the language, so there's most likely *some* reasonable use case for them.